# How to select top 3 repeat

Tags: pandas

This is the input

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.DataFrame({"top3":['a','a','a','b','a','a','b','b','c'],"desc":['a1','a2','a3','b3','a4','a5','b2','b1','c6']})
print(df)
```

The table

```
  top3 desc
0    a   a1
1    a   a2
2    a   a3
3    b   b3
4    a   a4
5    a   a5
6    b   b2
7    b   b1
8    c   c6
```

I want to get the top 3 repeat for `top3` column, here's the desired output

```
  top3 desc
0    a   a1
1    a   a2
2    a   a3
3    b   b3
4    b   b2
5    b   b1
6    c   c6
```

How should I do that using pandas processing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Goupby with head

```
>>> df.groupby(["top3"]).head(3).reset_index(drop=True)

  top3 desc
0    a   a1
1    a   a2
2    a   a3
3    b   b3
4    b   b2
5    b   b1
6    c   c6
```